# How to access minikube service remotely?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, pipeline, kubectl, minikube

I have installed minikube in remote rdp server(windows). I have deployed spring boot application and expose that deployment as a service using load balancer on specific port. I was able access the application inside the rdp. But when i tried to access it remotely it seems the site can't be reached. How to access the service from my remote system?

Comment: Please upvote/accept my answer if it has helped you. Thank you.

Comment: @l.vignesh David Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider accepting or upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I solved the above issue by using port forwarding command in minikube.